Using EF Core DbContext and ASP.NET Core Identity's UserManager simultaneously
My user entity:
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
  public Office Office { get; set; }      // not nullable
  // ...other custom properties
}

Suppose I want to create a new user:
var user = new User {
  UserName       = "foo",
  Email          = "foo@example.com",
  EmailConfirmed = true,
  Office         = await context.Offices.SingleAsync(x => x.Name == "Head Office"),
};
await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");

That throws:

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Office"

The reason is that Office was loaded in one context and used in the one encapsulated by UserManager (which tries to create a new one with the same PK).
The underlying context is not exposed, so one can't do userManager.Context.Attach(office) or similar.
I can see two workarounds:

Declare User.Office as nullable, then:
var user = ...
await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
user.Office = ...
_context.Attach(user);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

But I do not want to do that: I don't want to break my domain model (a user cannot exist without an office) because of a technical limitation in UserManager
I could create the user via DbContext instead of UserManager. But I do not want to do that either, because it handles all the auth-related stuff for me, and I don't want to take responsibility for any of that.

What other options exist?
(In case it is relevant: this is not in the context of a web request, but actually in a console app.)

Did you try also assigning OfficeId on new user, if that helps?

@MichałTurczyn I'm unsure what you mean? Do you mean to create the two entities at the same time? That would work. The problem is the Office is already in existence when I create a User.

Did you try var office = await ocntext.GetOffice and then user.OfficeId = office.Id

@MichałTurczyn That entity doesn't expose the PK. But that's another option, maybe the only one. Thanks!

@MichałTurczyn I identified the issue. I posted an answer and added your idea as another alternative. Thanks!

DId you try my suggestion? Does it work? And in ASP.NET Core, db context is one per each request, so this case is not applicable to ASP.NET Core :)

@MichałTurczyn By changing the entity to expose the PK I believe it should work, I added your idea to the answer below. Regaring per-request: that is the default (but can be changed on startup). You are right It's important that DbContext and UserManager are resolved from the same container and that they have the same lifetime. In my case that was the issue. Thanks for helping me diagnose the problem!

After much investigating here's what I found: if DbContext and UserManager are resolved from the same container, then the latter's underlying context will be the same instance as the former. (It is unfortunate though that it doesn't expose the context, so it can be used via Attach).
It didn't work that way for me because in my console app, the two things were resolved from two containers.
The best option is to ensure they are resolved from the same container (i.e. ServiceProvider).
If that's not possible then there are alternatives:

The two I already identified above
Another one in a comment by @MichałTurczyn: to expose a PK for the Office entity, and then user.OfficeId = officeId.

